# Java JPanel in BorderLayout positioning

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

Can I expand a child panel all the way from `BorderLayout.LINE_START` to `BorderLayout.LINE_END`, fill all the space from right to left including the center ?

I am trying to accomplish as below...

```
+-------------------------+
|                         |
+-------------------------+
|     PANEL OCCUPYING     |
|         ALL THIS        |
|          SPACE          |
+-------------------------+
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: If nothing else occupies the space in between it should be possible, otherwise no. The other components will apply there own size requirements to the individual positions.  What is it you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @camickr, for some reason, I keep getting empty spaces on the right and left...

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Agreed (with camickr) looks like center position to me

Comment: I just tried a more simplified example, and It works... I'll go back to my code and check where does that space comes from... thank you all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the `CENTER` of the BorderLayout.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and examples.

> for some reason, I keep getting empty spaces on the right and left...

The `CENTER` will occupy all the space available. So it depends on the component that you add to the `CENTER`. Maybe you are adding a panel and the panel expands, but the component on the panel doesn't expand because by default a panel uses a `FlowLayout` and FlowLayout respects the preferred size of the components added to it.

Comment: I got the problem.. obviously, because I had many panels, I forgot to set the layout of the parent panel to borderlayout... now all is ok.. thanks.